# Running Gemnasium-python on code that depends on psycopg2

Tags: python, docker, gitlab

I'm trying to setup a Gitlab instance with Dependency Scanning, but the code I'm trying to analyse depends on `psycopg2`.

The script snippet looks like this:

```
- docker run
  --env DEP_SCAN_DISABLE_REMOTE_CHECKS="${DEP_SCAN_DISABLE_REMOTE_CHECKS:-false}"
  --volume "$PWD:/code"
  --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  "registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/dependency-scanning:$SP_VERSION" /code/
```

And I can see how Gitlab is pulling the image, then starting to install the libraries in my `requirements.txt`, but when it gets to the point where it should install `psycopg2`, it fails because it can't find `pg_config`.

```
$ export SP_VERSION=$(echo "$CI_SERVER_VERSION" | sed 's/^\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]*\).*/\1-\2-stable/')
$ docker run --env DEP_SCAN_DISABLE_REMOTE_CHECKS="${DEP_SCAN_DISABLE_REMOTE_CHECKS:-false}" --volume "$PWD:/code" --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock "registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/dependency-scanning:$SP_VERSION" /code/
Unable to find image 'registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/dependency-scanning:11-7-stable' locally
11-7-stable: Pulling from gitlab-org/security-products/dependency-scanning
6dee6a11e61b: Pulling fs layer
6dee6a11e61b: Verifying Checksum
6dee6a11e61b: Download complete
6dee6a11e61b: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:bac83170c80e91c4d0132748e03248492808b463794cae51760218a80cbe2580
Status: Downloaded newer image for registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/dependency-scanning:11-7-stable
2019/02/11 00:49:27 Copy project directory to containers
2019/02/11 00:49:27 [bundler-audit] Detect project using plugin
2019/02/11 00:49:27 [bundler-audit] Project not compatible
2019/02/11 00:49:27 [gemnasium] Detect project using plugin
2019/02/11 00:49:27 [gemnasium] Project not compatible
2019/02/11 00:49:27 [gemnasium-maven] Detect project using plugin
2019/02/11 00:49:27 [gemnasium-maven] Project not compatible
2019/02/11 00:49:27 [gemnasium-python] Detect project using plugin
2019/02/11 00:49:27 [gemnasium-python] Project is compatible
2019/02/11 00:49:27 [gemnasium-python] Starting analyzer...
2: Pulling from gitlab-org/security-products/analyzers/gemnasium-python
cd784148e348: Pulling fs layer
a5ca736b15eb: Pulling fs layer
f320f547ff02: Pulling fs layer
2edd8ff8cb8f: Pulling fs layer
9381128744b2: Pulling fs layer
a2a81dd1e4fb: Pulling fs layer
797b4f744fac: Pulling fs layer
9381128744b2: Waiting
a2a81dd1e4fb: Waiting
797b4f744fac: Waiting
2edd8ff8cb8f: Waiting
a5ca736b15eb: Verifying Checksum
a5ca736b15eb: Download complete
cd784148e348: Verifying Checksum
cd784148e348: Download complete
cd784148e348: Pull complete
2edd8ff8cb8f: Verifying Checksum
2edd8ff8cb8f: Download complete
9381128744b2: Verifying Checksum
9381128744b2: Download complete
f320f547ff02: Verifying Checksum
f320f547ff02: Download complete
a5ca736b15eb: Pull complete
a2a81dd1e4fb: Verifying Checksum
a2a81dd1e4fb: Download complete
797b4f744fac: Verifying Checksum
797b4f744fac: Download complete
f320f547ff02: Pull complete
2edd8ff8cb8f: Pull complete
9381128744b2: Pull complete
a2a81dd1e4fb: Pull complete
797b4f744fac: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:75ce781b990a7a26ecde5ab1d1b59ed01adf2c5c35fbb622d21ef5f92b0b6001
Status: Downloaded newer image for registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/analyzers/gemnasium-python:2
Found project in /tmp/app
Collecting redis==2.10.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3b/f6/7a76333cf0b9251ecf49efff635015171843d9b977e4ffcf59f9c4428052/redis-2.10.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (64kB)
Collecting decorator==4.2.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e1/5a/53db15bf367d2028bdc6700dbdf1bdfab46b9f208b7516952817c0808118/decorator-4.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Django==2.0.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/89/f9/94c20658f0cdecc2b6607811e2c0bb042408a51f589e5ad0cb0eac3236a1/Django-2.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (7.1MB)
Collecting djangorestframework==3.8 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8b/5f/20900529b5849b446b47382b7095fba81383af6240e731ce6cd50f4e0a68/djangorestframework-3.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (923kB)
Collecting django-filter==2.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6a/8b/8517167a0adc45ce94d0873efb9487dd4cdeff7e10f96e837ad3d58f5837/django_filter-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (69kB)
Collecting markdown==2.6.11 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6d/7d/488b90f470b96531a3f5788cf12a93332f543dbab13c423a5e7ce96a0493/Markdown-2.6.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (78kB)
Collecting properties==0.3.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/81/39/3d7dac15b04d8389c64396ad2788d59df184720e88029e466e53c02ad6bd/properties-0.3.3.tar.gz
Collecting psycopg2-binary==2.7.7 (from -r requirements.txt (line 16))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dd/56/c22da10f5a725d61c58a185ec0f803aa2d384646ee8eb83d8ce88ed5edb1/psycopg2-binary-2.7.7.tar.gz (428kB)
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/psycopg2_binary.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2_binary.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2_binary.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2_binary.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2_binary.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

    Error: pg_config executable not found.

    pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
    containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
    option:

        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

    If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
    'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).


    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-99sq6mw_/psycopg2-binary/
You are using pip version 18.1, however version 19.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
2019/02/11 00:49:32 exit status 1
2019/02/11 00:49:33 Container exited with non zero status code
```

The problem is obvious. It can't find a binary, which lives inside a package named `libpq-dev`. The solution is not that obvious thou. I don't know how to install that library in the image.

Any idea how can I make the dependency scanner to install libpq-dev?

Comment: Write a `Dockerfile` to add the binary to the image.

Comment: @KlausD. The problem is that the binary from the first command (dependency scanning) is running another docker image (gemnasium-python). I can't override that one.

Comment: Of cause you can, just tag it the same.